# Xamarin MVVM structure & binding

Tags: xamarin, mvvm, binding

I want to create a survey per oulet. I have db table that indicates which question should be enabled/disabled for particular outlet. There is also the table with user responses including outlet id and answer for each question (should be null for disabled questions). I guess I should create separate models - one for question setup (bool) and one for actual values entered by a user. After user completes the survey I want to save the answers to the db. Setup is just one way.

As I understand each view can have only one BindingContext. Should I then combine question setup and values into one to bind them to view in one time - bool to IsEnabled property and values to other respective property? And process just the values after the survey is completed? Should be all this handled by the view model?

I'm new to MVVM and I could not figure out how this should be done properly. Could anyone please help me?

Many thanks.
Michal

Comment: First try to see the youtube tutorials from Stuart Lodge (MvvmCross) before starting to work.

Comment: MvvmCross is obsolete for Xamarin Forms I guess.